# Mathematical formula evaluation in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, math, eval

I want to evaluate a mathematical function existing in some cell in Microsoft Excel with some value from other cell, let say that in the A1 cell the user writes “X^2+2X+5” and in the cell A2 writes 3, I want to obtain the result on A3 equals to 20 (the function evaluation for X=3). The idea is writing a macro that has two parameters, the first one, the expression and the other the variable value. Where can I find the code (VB Excel Macro) for doing this without starting from zero? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Application.Evaluate`, e.g.

```
application.Evaluate(replace([A1],"X",[A2]))
```

You'll have to update your formula to `X^2+2*X+5`